# Convert a List / Map to org.apache.flink.util.Collector

Tags: java, apache-flink

How can I convert a List / Map to org.apache.flink.util.Collector?

Lets say I have this:

```
List<Tuple2<Double, Integer>> list = new ArrayList<Tuple2<Double, Integer>>();
```

And I want to get something like this:

```
Collector<Tuple2<Double, Integer>> data = ... list.getCollector();
```

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use this [ListCollector](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/api/java/org/apache/flink/api/common/functions/util/ListCollector.html) as bridge, with this class you can translate your List (ArrayList) into a Collector(ListCollector), using the [constructor](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/api/java/org/apache/flink/api/common/functions/util/ListCollector.html#ListCollector-java.util.List-)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @karelss

This is the solution:

```
List<Tuple2<Double, Integer>> list = new ArrayList<Tuple2<Double, Integer>>();
list.add(...);
Collector<Tuple2<Double, Integer>> data = new ListCollector<>(list);
```

Comment: You are wellcome :)